# Show/hide rows with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am using some modified code from another post.  Basically I want to switch between showing 10 rows of a table to showing all rows (50 for example).  I have got it to show from 10 rows to all, however what I need to do now is code it so that if I click the div again it toggles or resets back to showing 10 rows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var numShown = 10; // Initial rows shown & index
var numRows = $('tbody').find('tr').length;
var numLeft = numRows - numShown;

$(document).ready(function(){
 // Hide rows and add clickable div
 $('tbody')
  .find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end() 
  $('#table_wrapper').after('<div id="more">Show all offers <span>
     (' + numLeft + ' more)</span></div>');

 $('#more').click(function(){
  numShown = numShown + numRows;
  $('tbody').find('tr:lt('+numShown+')').show(); 
  $("#more").html("Show top 10 offers");
 })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the uses of the `.toggle()` method:

```
$('#more').toggle(
           function(){
             numShown = numShown + numRows;
             $('tbody').find('tr:lt('+numShown+')').show(); 
             $("#more").html("Show top 10 offers");
           }, function() {
             // set the local vars you need here
             $('tbody').find('tr:gt('+(numShown-1)+')').hide();
             $('#more').html('Show all offers <span>('+numLeft+' more)</span>');
           });
```

Since there's no markup I'm not sure if that's exactly what will work with your setup, but the point is to reset the rows in their initial state in the second function of `toggle()`

Comment: I didn't know about that form of `toggle`. I wonder how jQuery knows about the "state" the table is in :-?

Comment: Is there anything I could add so that when the toggle collapes/hides the rows again, the browser viewpoint returns to the bottom of the table (its original position)?

Comment: Yeah, just add this to the end of the second function: `$(window).scrollTop($('#more').offset().top);` (or replace the `#more` with whatever selector you want to scroll to)

Comment: Thanks mVChr, that helps as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#more').click(function(){
    if(numShown <= 10)
    {
        //show some more
        numShown = numShown + numRows;
        $('tbody').find('tr:lt('+numShown+')').show(); 
        $("#more").html("Show top 10 offers");
    }
    else
    {
        //hide some rows
        numShown = 10;
        $('tbody').find('tr:gt('+numShown+')').hide(); 
        $("#more").html("Show more");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use addClass() to hide rows, by adding a class styled with `display: none;` in my CSS stylesheet. Then to show the previously hidden rows, all I've to do is select the rows with this class and remove the class from them. Sth like:

```
$('.hidden_row').removeClass('hidden_row');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(some_selector)` returns a list of matching elements. You can call [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) on them, and do whatever you want on each of the elements. Note that the items in the list are not jquery objects, but the default DOM objects (those you get from the `getElementBy...` methods). You can either work on these or do `$(domobject)` to get a jquery object again.